# Filtering words starting with '\' from Python

Tags: python, string, filter, python-2.x, tweepy

I am acquiring tweets from twitter and I want to do term frequency but avoiding emoticons and strange characters. I have seen that this characters haver the following form: u'*' so they always start with \ but when I try to put this character as a filter it does not allowed me due to \ is a special character. Do you know how can I filter this kind of words?
I attach the 10 most common words I have:

```
 [(u'#ElClasico', 3311),
 (u'RT', 2839),
 (u'\ud83d', 1425),
 (u'#Messi', 1369),
 (u'\u2026', 1092),
 (u'Messi', 975),
 (u'Barcelona', 964),
 (u'\u2705', 948),
 (u'Most', 944),
 (u'500', 903)]
```

I would like to erase the u'\ud83d', u'\2026' and u'\2705'

Comment: U+D83D is a surrogate, indicating that you've already corrupted your input. U+2026 is a punctuation mark. You should be very careful about filtering your input -- what will you do about accented letters, for example?

Comment: so what do you recommend to erase the special characters which are not words?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter out non-Latin characters, then you can utilize the library [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

```
from regex import VERSION1, UNICODE, compile

# remove non-Latin characters.
compile(ur'\p{^Latin}+', VERSION1 | UNICODE).sub('', YOUR_INPUT)

# remove non-Latin/non-space/non-punctuation characters.
compile(ur'[^\p{Latin}\p{Zs}\p{Po}]+', VERSION1 | UNICODE).sub('', YOUR_INPUT)
```

C.f.:

- [Unicode Character Categories](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)

Comment: thank you very much but the problem is that using the first compile I get this output now: The most used words in English are: [(u'', 10041), (u'ElClasico', 3311), (u'RT', 2839), (u'Messi', 2444), (u'Barcelona', 1011), (u'Most', 944), (u'Lionel', 872), (u'goals', 834), (u'goal', 767), (u'th', 633)]      So I would like to erase the emoticon tems, not just change them for a ''